# search record in database with TablerowSorter and rowFilter

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc

i managed to have a code that is able to filter records in database, displaying the result in my jtable..here is the code below:

```
try{
     TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(((DefaultTableModel)myTable.getModel()));
    sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(JTextField.getText()));
    myTable.setRowSorter(sorter);
    }catch(Exception e){
    e.getMessage();
    }
```

the problem is, when i click on the selected row record i have searched for, i am unable to get its data into a desired textfield..
the method for the table_click is as follows:

```
        try{
            int row = myTable.getSelectedRow();
            String table_click=(myTable.getModel().getValueAt(row,0).toString());
            String sgl="select * from employees where Name='"+table_click+"'";
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sgl);
            rs=pst.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){
                String a = rs.getString("Name");
                JTextField.setText(a);        
            }
        }catch(SQLException | NumberFormatException e){
            e.getMessage();
        }finally{
            try{
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }
        }
```

and what this does is to only select the record in the first row in the database but not the searched record.
please how do i click my jTable to select only the record i have searched for but not the first record in the database when i use TableRowSorter and rowFilter? thank you.

Comment: Why you are using `prepareStatement` and you use concatenation like this `Name='"+table_click+"'"`? **Hint**, maybe there are more then one employee who have the same name, I think It's better to search with the id instead

Comment: i tried that but it doesnt solve the problem.

Comment: Which column `myTable.getModel().getValueAt(row,0).toString()` represent in your table?

Comment: it represents the 'Name Column'.

Comment: am thinking the search method filters only the table model but not the real database. so though jtable looks filtered, it has no impact on the actual database so anytime the table is clicked, it picks up the first row record by default. is there a way to sort and filter the records so that it affects not only the table model but the real database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

If you only want the name to be displayed in the textfield then do not run a query for it again.
1st print the **String table_click** once to make sure it has the desired value and if it does, then simply

```
JTextField.setText(table_click);
```

If u specifically want to for some reason get this done from the database, then again first print **String table_click** to make sure that it gets the desired value, also make sure that there are not multiple records with the same name in your database. then if all of that is correct then try writing the PreparedStatement the traditional way.

```
pst = conn.PrepareStatement("select * from employees where Name = ?;");
pst.setString(1,table_click);
pst.executeQuery();
if (!rs.isBeforeFirst()) {
                System.out.println("Empty ResultSet");
            }
else{

JTextField.setText(rs.getString("Name"));
}
```